# Dragging a rectangle over image

Tags: javascript

I'd like to be able to drag a rectangle over an image, and retrieve the coordinates of the end-points. Is there a library that'll take care of visualizing the rectangle as it's being dragged?

Answer (score 5):

[jCrop](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php) does something similar to what you're looking for. I think the proper term for this is "rubber-banding."